I need to refresh page to signInWithEmailAndPassword
This is my Login Component:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import {signInWithEmailAndPassword} from "firebase/auth";
import {auth} from "./firebase.js"

export default LoginComponent = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(() => {
            navigate('/')
        }).catch((error) => {
        });
    };

My AuthProvider:
import {onAuthStateChanged,} from "firebase/auth";
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {auth} from "./firebase.js";

export const AuthContext = createContext(null);

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (currentUser) => {
            if (currentUser) {
                setAccessToken(await currentUser.getIdToken(true));
            }
            setUser(currentUser);
            setLoading(false);
        });

        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);

    const authValue = {
        user,
        loading,
        accessToken,
    };

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={authValue}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

AuthProvider.propTypes = {
children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export default AuthProvider;

On my routes page, I am doing this:
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { AuthContext } from "./components/Auth/AuthProvider.js";
import UserProfile from "./components/UserProfile"

const App = () => {
    const { user, loading } = useContext(AuthContext);

    function LandingPageRedirect({ children }) {
        if (loading) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>; 
        }
        if (user) {
            return <>{children}</>
        } else {
            return (
                <Navigate
                to="/landing"
                state={{
                    from: location.pathname,
                }}
                replace
                />
            )
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={
                            <LandingPageRedirect>
                                <Home />
                            </LandingPageRedirect>
                        } 
                    />

However, after sign in I am being sent back to"/landing" rather than "/home". I need to refresh the page in order to be sent to the home page rather than landing page. How do I fix this?

Possibly you navigate to '/' before you set user to state. It can happen because of waiting while promise from getIdToken be resolved or even authStateChange call happens after navigation. I have many solutions for you which you can try. Firstly let's move setUser before that getToken call in case it doesn't help you will find another solution below.
Like this:
useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (currentUser) => {
            setUser(currentUser);
            if (currentUser) {
                setAccessToken(await currentUser.getIdToken(true));
            }
            
            setLoading(false);
        });

        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);

or rewrite it without await.
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
    setUser(currentUser);
    currentUser
      .getIdToken(true)
      .then((token) => {
        setAccessToken(token);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  });

  return () => unsubscribe();
}, []);

Or divide this logic to two different useEffect function calls:
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
    setUser(currentUser);
    setLoading(false);
  });

  return () => unsubscribe();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (currentUser) {
    currentUser
      .getIdToken(true)
      .then((token) => {
        setAccessToken(token);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}, [currentUser]);

In case it doesn't work stick with next solution I suggested.
As you can see in the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword
signinwithemailandpassword returns Promise that has user inside
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth#usercredential
So you can setUser in then block.
So expose your setUser from the authProvider.
Modified code:
const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (currentUser) => {
            if (currentUser) {
                setAccessToken(await currentUser.getIdToken(true));
            }
            setUser(currentUser);
            setLoading(false);
        });

        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);

    const authValue = {
        user,
        loading,
        accessToken,
        setUser
    };

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={authValue}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

Update your handleSubmit
const { setUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
...
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((res) => {
            setUser(res.user);
            navigate('/')
        }).catch((error) => {
        });
    };

After that the application won't redirect you to landing.

I don't understand. Shouldn't my authprovider be fetching new user credentials on page load? I shouldn't need to do that

The onAuthStateChanged listener should indeed already accomplish this. You might want to put a breakpoint in there, run in a debugger, and see if it ever reaches it.

You navigate to '/' before onAuthStateChanged likely it can happen because of   if (currentUser) {
setAccessToken(await currentUser.getIdToken(true));
} . I'll modify my answer. one moment
